# How do I tell which case is valid in a variant record when the case variable isn't named, and how do I create values of such records?

Tags: delphi, memory-management, data-structures

I've been reading about "case" within records and I still have some open questions about it. (http://www.delphibasics.co.uk/Article.asp?Name=Records)

I use the example:

```
type 
   TRect = packed record
     case Integer of
       0: (Left, Top, Right, Bottom: Integer);
       1: (TopLeft, BottomRight: TPoint);
   end;
```

The example basically tells me that the first member/property of `TRect` is an `Integer` (which this `Integer` has no name!). If this (unnamed!) integer is `0` or `1` it just adds the corresponding members:

```
(0 for Left, Top, Right, Bottom)
(1 for TopLeft, BottomRight)
```

So let's say there is content in memory which I would like to use this record on.
I fairly add a new `type` that represents a pointer to `TRect`. The new record would look like this:

```
type
   PRect = ^TRect; 
   TRect = packed record
     case Integer of
       0: (Left, Top, Right, Bottom: Integer);
       1: (TopLeft, BottomRight: TPoint);
   end;
```

So the content (in memory) would sorta like this:

```
First Integer = 0 // determines the case!
Left          = 1
Top           = 2
Right         = 3
Bottom        = 4
```

This content has a total size of 20 bytes in memory and has the address of X.

To output my content I would typecast this address like this: `PRect(X)`

Now how do I know my record has the "0" or the "1" case?!

How could I also create a record with the case of "0" or "1"?

I'm extremely confused by this and would like to know if I understood the use of `case` in records...

Comment: *"case **command**"*?! Do not ever use that delphibasics, it is crappy and does more harm than help. Always read [proper documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records) first.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not understanding correctly. :-)

The record always has the same layout in memory, and always has both `0` and `1` parts of the `case` section. You don't create one or the other. The one that is used is decided by how you access the record automatically; both cases always exist.

`TRect` is a good example. If you create a new `TRect` using the `Rect` function, you've got a single `TRect` record that has both the `0` and `1` parts available:

```
var
  R: TRect;
  RTop, RLeft: Integer;
  RTopLeft: TPoint;


  R := Rect(0, 0, 100, 100);
  RTop := R.Top;             // Access TRect.Top separately
  RLeft := R.Left;           // Access TRect.Left separately
  RTopLeft := R.TopLeft;     // Access TRect.TopLeft, which is both Top and Left

  if RTopLeft.X = 0     // This is true, because we created the R rect with 0, 0
                        // as the left and top

  if RTop = 0        // This is also true, for the same reason
```

Another example of how this works is directly from the [documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records). Your code can use the named tag part of the record (`Salaried`) to determine which part of the variant portion it should access. Note that *both parts still exist* at the same time, though.

```
type
   TEmployee = record
   FirstName, LastName: string[40];
   BirthDate: TDate;
   case Salaried: Boolean of
     True: (AnnualSalary: Currency);
     False: (HourlyWage: Currency);
 end;

var
  Person: TEmployee;

  Person.FirstName := 'John';
  Person.LastName := 'Smith';
  Person.BirthDate := EncodeDate(1980, 1, 1);
```

Both the `AnnualSalary` and `HourlyWage` exist in memory; which of the two cases are available depends on which one you access:

```
  // If this person is paid by the hour
  Person.Salaried := False;
  Person.HourlyWage := 20.00;

  // If this person is paid an annual salary instead
  Person.Salaried := True;
  Person.AnnualSalary := 80000.00;

  // You can access both at the same time. Of course, it wouldn't make
  // any sense to do so in this case.
  if (Person.Salaried and (Person.AnnualSalary > 60000)) then
    DoSomething
  else if (not Person.Salaried) and (Person.HourlyWage > 15.00) then
    DoSomethingElse;
```

The `tag` name (as pointed out by David Heffernan and Free Consulting in the comments) takes space in the memory allocation.

```
program TestRec;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

uses
  SysUtils;
type
  TTestNoTagName = record    // No tag name on variant part
    I: Integer;
    case Boolean of             
        True: (X, Y: Integer);
        False: (A, B: Integer;)
  end;

type
  TTestWithTagName = record  // Tag name on variant part
    I: Integer;
    case Dummy: Boolean of
      True: (X, Y: Integer);
      False: (A, B: Integer);
  end;

begin
  WriteLn('TTestNoTagName: ', SizeOf(TTestNoTagName));      // SizeOf(12)
  WriteLn('TTestWithTagName: ', SizeOf(TTestWithTagName));  // SizeOf(16)
  ReadLn;
end.
```

(And thanks to @davea for spotting the mistake in my initial test code.)

Comment: I see. Thank you for clearing that up. So it actually allocates both states?

Comment: No. :-) It allocates the same amount of memory both ways (whatever amount will hold both cases); the only difference is in the way you access it.

Comment: @KenWhite, you failed to elaborate on tag field. In the fact you completely forgot about it in the part of example written by you.

Comment: @Free: The `tag` field is covered in the documentation I linked, and in fact is meaningless. There's no need to elaborate on it. "In the variant part, tag is optional and can be any valid identifier. If you omit tag, omit the colon (:) after it as well."

Comment: You have a misconception. What really stated there is what tag is **optional**, not ignored "meaningless" symbol. *The tag, if there is one, functions as an **extra field in the non-variant part** of the record.* Hence, you initialized all the fields but forgot a tag.

Comment: I'm really sorry, but you do. Your undisclosed experiment with `SizeOf` is probably flawed due another mistakes. Tag field behaves exactly as documented - not being ignored. http://ideone.com/GC9Quh

Comment: In other words: `case Integer of` is different from `case i : Integer of` - both are legal, but produce different results.

Comment: @KenWhite No, if you include a tag then it takes space. If you omit the tag, no space is allocated. You really should address this in the answer.

Comment: You're calling SizeOf(TTestNoTag) twice.

Comment: I wonder why is your `TTestWithTagName` is packed, although it is not `packed`.

Comment: @Sertac: Because apparently I'm having trouble typing the right keys today. :-) It's a typo. I'll fix. (I originally used both packed and not packed in my test code; removed it, but didn't update output.)

Answer (score 3):

<sub>What is missing from the [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20450638/205376) as well as from the [on-line documentation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Structured_Types#Variant_Parts_in_Records) is an important fact what:</sub>

`tag` field (if present) as well as its type plays absolutely(!) no role in the accessing fields of the variant part of record. Moreover, present `tag` field treated the same way as regular field declared outside of variant part, so for example both `TEmployee.AnnualSalary` and `TEmployee.HourlyWage` variant fields can be accessed independently of the value of `TEmployee.Salaried` tag field. The type of tag is arbitrarily chosen ordinal type and can be used for self-documentation purposes, as demonstrated in `TFigure` example.

---

<sub>Answering to another misconception might be developed while reading delphibasic text:</sub>

All of variant part of record occupy the same memory region, so the size of whole group of variant parts in memory equals to the size of largest particular variant part in group.

```
{ this record occupies SizeOf(Word) = 2*SizeOf(Byte) bytes in memory }
TWordCracker = packed record
  case Integer of
    0: (W: Word);
    1: (Lo, Hi: Byte);
    2: (Bytes: packed array [0..1] of Byte);
end;
```

Comment: @KenWhite, when you erased your comment (and all of your traces), your downvote because unhelpful reaction on the competing answer.

Comment: Sorry. You're making the assumption (and we know what that means) that I'm the one who downvoted. I decided to remove my comment because I responded to your comment to my answer instead.

Comment: The documentation is missing nothing. It says: *You can read or write to any field of any variant at any time*.

Answer (score 1):

When the case contain no identifier, the different cases can be read  meaningfull at any time, because a Tpoint and two integers are binary compatible.
Since there are no identifier, the integer in the case statement is a dummy, that takes up no space in the record.

```
Trect = packed record
  case Integer of
    0: (Left, Top, Right, Bottom: Integer);
    1: (TopLeft, BottomRight: TPoint);
end;
```

When the case contains an identifier, eg

```
type tperson = record
  case married : boolean of
  true :  (dateofmarriage : tdate);
  false : (evermarried : boolean; dateofdivorce  : tdate);  
end;
```

by examine married, you now which of the recordstructures to use.